# If $p$, $r$ satisfy $|p|,\, |r| \le 1$ and $1=\lambda p + (1-\lambda)r$ for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$ then $p=r=1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

If $p$, $r$ are real numbers and $|p|,\, |r| \le  1$ and there exists $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $1=\lambda p + (1-\lambda)r$ then $p=r=1$.

Not sure why this is true? Can anybody help?

#### Context

It was in relation to extreme points. I'm trying to prove this and then use it to show that $(1,0)$ is an extreme point of $S=\{x \in R^2 : \|x\|_{L^1} \le 1\}$. Causing me some issues.

Comment: Yes, this is clearly functional analysis.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: It shows that 1 is an extreme point of the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}$, so it's probably some lemma in a proof of Krein-Milman.

Comment: Ah, ok that explains it. @Nate, but taken out of context it hardly classifies as functional analysis.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, it was in relation to extreme points. I'm trying to prove and then use it to show that (1,0) is an extreme point of $S=\{x in R^2 : L1 norm(x) <=1}. Causing me some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose without loss of generality that $p \le r$.  Conclude that $1 \le r$ and hence $r=1$.  Then rearrange to obtain $0 = (p-1)\epsilon$.

Comment: So $1\leq r$ because |p| is less than 1? And because r is less than or equal to 1 then it must equal r. I don't understand the rearrange part though.

Comment: @davim1992: Because $p \le r$.  $$1 = \epsilon p + (1-\epsilon) r \le \epsilon r + (1-\epsilon) r = r.$$

Comment: Ah okay. I'm an idiot apparently. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Does this also hold if it was $$0=\lambda p +(1-\lambda)r)$$?

Comment: So p=r=0 in this case?

Comment: @davim1992: No, we could have for example $p=-1/2$, $r=1/2$.  But if $-1 = \lambda p + (1-\lambda) r$ you could conclude by a similar argument that $p=r=-1$.